# change text box text if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I want to change text box text depending if checkbox is checked or not. So if the user checks the checkbox, the text box shows some text and if the user unchecked the checkbox, it shows some different text.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<input id="txt" type="text" value="aaaa" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if (!$('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#txt').val('checked');
    }
    else{
        $('#txt').val('unchecked');
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/15L2vq3k/)**

Comment: You're not binding to any events. Bind to checkbox change event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try binding to the click event:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        $('#txt').val('checked');
    }
    else{
        $('#txt').val('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: ! from the first if needs to be removed.

Comment: Removed ! as per artm

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
       if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
         $('#txt').val('checked');
       }
       else{
         $('#txt').val('unchecked');
       }
    });

});
```

check the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/15L2vq3k/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to use `.change()` and `this.checked` like so:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
<input id="txt" type="text" value="unchecked" />


$('#check').change(function(){
    var checkChange = this.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked';
    $('#txt').val(checkChange);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15L2vq3k/4/)**