# Change button link depending on which radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, radio-button

I have 5 radio buttons and depending of which one is selected I want to change the `href` link of an image, which sends you to another page. Example: I selected the first radio button. When I click the image, the page "gallery" opens. When I select the second radio button and press the image, it'll open the page "about me"... is there any solution for this with JavaScript?

This is my radio set:

```
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide6">
```

and this is the button:

```
<div id="down_icon2">
    <a href="">
        <img src="images/down_icon.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: no i am not good at javascript :/

Comment: I suggest research a bit more, your question will get a lot of negative responses. Here are a couple of links, took me 10 seconds to find, literally : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171189/change-text-box-text-if-checkbox-is-checked, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282219/check-uncheck-all-the-checkboxes-in-a-table

Comment: One to change the 'href' https://gist.github.com/iruslani/2855503

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function to check which radio button is set,
the function sets the desired link.

```html
<input checked="" type="radio" name="slider" id="slide1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" >
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide6">

<a href="" onclick='myFunction()' id="myLink">MyLink</a>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
   
        if(document.getElementById('slide1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('myLink').href = "test.php";
        }
    }
</script>
```

you can do the same with the image src

Edit: it is just the case for the first radio button, you have to add the test for the other buttons.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! this worked perfectly for me :) i was struggling like the whole day with googling and trying and you did this in a few minutes for me :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="radio" data-image="http://www.placecage.com/200/300" name="slider" id="slide1">
```

add a data-image to all the slides with the image you want. Then with Jquery you can do this:

```
$("input").click(function () {
  var clickedRadio = $(this).attr("data-image");
  $("img").attr("src", clickedRadio);
})
```

If you click any input it sets the src of the image to the data-image of the clicked item ;) Note this uses [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) library

Also here is a working example [codepen](http://codepen.io/rikato/pen/yexqJj)

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but another answer was easier to understand for a dummy like me :D

Comment: Well ofcourse we can all explain why this works but learning javascript is up to yourself this should atleast get you started.

Answer (score 1):

That is the answer, it's just use native javascript.it can wrote better if you use extra lib like jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/mham9ons/

just use your html:

```
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide2" data-href="xxx1">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide3" data-href="xxx2">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide4" data-href="xxx3">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide5" data-href="xxx4">
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="slide6" data-href="xxx5">

<div id="down_icon2"><a href=""><img src="images/down_icon.png"></a></div>
```

add these code:

```
var sliders = document.getElementsByName('slider');
var linkWrapper = document.getElementById('down_icon2');

for (var i in sliders){
    if(sliders[i].addEventListener){
    sliders[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       linkWrapper.childNodes[0].setAttribute('href', this.getAttribute('data-href'));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but another answer was easier to understand for a dummy like me :D